# Can Facebook Events be integrated from an external site?

Tags: facebook, facebook-events

Could someone please tell me if it is possible to integrate with Facebook Events? In other words, pass some parameters to create an event from an external site and forward invites to via Facebook (and via your Facebook friends list).

Comment: You can create events via the Facebook API.  Questions about programming with the api would be better asked on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to integrate with Facebook's API - agreed with @rchern though the **details** of which are best discussed on StackOverflow. The relevant API page is http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Events.create

Comment: Personally I think you asked in the right place for a "can you" but may need to change the wording next time (slightly). Or ask "how" on stackoverflow (assuming blindly that anything is possible with the wealth of programming talent on the site).

Comment: Just as on StackOverflow, questions asking how would be better than can here. Integration leads to API, which leads to programming, which leads to SO.